# Transforming the data stored in a CSV or parquet file to feed a Keras lstm model using a generator in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, lstm

I have a very long dataframe (25 million rows x 500 columns) which I can access as a CSV file or a parquet file but I can load into the RAM of my PC.

The data should be shaped appropriately in order to become input to a Keras LSTM model (Tensorflow 2), given a desired number of timestamps per sample and a desired number of samples per batch.

While this describes the real situation I am facing, to simplify things and make them concrete and reproducible let's assume a dataframe shaped 1000 rows x 3 columns where the first two columns are features and the last is the target, while each row corresponds to a timestamp.  Let's assume further that we would like to transform the data so that each sample contains 5 timesteps having as target the label corresponding to the last (most recent) timestamp.   We want to feed the data to a keras lstm model with batches containing each 32 samples.

The data are in our hard disk in CSV or parquet format.  We can not load all the data to our RAM.

How we would go about it?  More specifically, could we use a TensorFlow generator to accomplish this objective and how?  How can I find a solution using the example specs provided above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is converting your `.csv` file to `.tfrecord` format, this data format is designed for handling the "my data doesn't fit in to memory case'. If you write your own generator, your trying to mimic the behavior of the `.tfrecord`s. Do you really need the data to be in `.csv` format?

If your really want the generator, start from [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#from_generator):

```
import csv 
def generator:
  with open("data.csv", "r"):
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
      yield row

# you'll have to define your timestamp as a string. Your
# data description is not too clear so adapt to your needs.
output_types = (tf.int32, tf.string. tf.int32)

data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator,
    output_types)
```

Using this method might create a bottleneck for I/O for training your network. I strongly advise you convert your data to `.tfrecords`, especially an LSTM - which probably will take a long time to train - as using `.tfrecords` also reduces training time, as it enables `tensorflow` to optimize the I/O.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure what you mean though "you'll have to define your timestamp as a string. Your data description is not too clear so adapt to your needs."?  I just propose a toy dataset that can be created by anyone who would like to answer the question.  What description for this toy dataset would you propose?

Comment: Possibly you would like to answer the follow-up question I posted here and which assumes that the data are indeed stored in .tfrecord format as you suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126186/transforming-the-data-stored-in-rtfm-format-to-become-inputs-to-a-lstm-keras-mod